# Iterative Hard Thresholding always thresholds same indices

Tags: compressive-sensing

I am confused by the fact that the thresholded indices in IHT do not change during the recovery. I used the code from [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13755/iterative-hard-thresholding-python-implementation) and also added the condition that $$\vert \vert \Phi \vert \vert_2 < 1$$ by

```
# Generate problem instance
A = np.random.randn(n,N)
# normalize to columns to have unit norm
A = A/(np.linalg.norm(A,2)+0.1)
```

Is it correct that always the same indices are kept/thresholded? For example:
$$x_0 = [ 0.1923, 0, 0, -0.2234, 0 ]$$
$$x_1 = [-0.1234, 0, 0,  2.6289, 0 ]$$
$$x_2 = [ 3.9432, 0, 0, -0.0012, 0 ]$$
$$x_3 = [-1.2345, 0, 0,  0.1298, 0 ]$$
$$ ... $$
for any $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 5}$. If IHT will always keep the same indices being not zero, I could find the best approximation by solving a simple equation system, therefore I guess there is an error in the code, isn't it?

Comment: Please add more details on your question . "the fact that the thresholded indices in IHT do not change during the recovery" is intrinsic of the algorithm or your implementation shows such a behavior?  Which part of "this question"?

Comment: It was correctly edited

Comment: How were your measurements taken - e.g. did you add noise?

Comment: Could you share the signals you are trying to find their representations?